# Jquery show hide issue on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, toggle, instagram

I am creating a simple show/hide all toggle button for my images in my instagram feed. It works fine in the fiddle but when I put the same code on my server nothing works with no error. Can anyone help me troubleshoot why this isn't working.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="btn btn-success toggleAll">
    Show All/Hide All
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
$('.toggleAll').on('click',function(){
    $('.pp, .coat, .heart-wrap, .comment-wrap, .check-wrap, .grip .btn').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

and here is the jsfiddle that works

https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/ua0ojhhe/5/

Here is my site where it doesn't work

http://galnova.com

Any help is welcome guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggleAll', function(){
    $('.pp, .coat, .heart-wrap, .comment-wrap, .check-wrap, .grip .btn').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: James this worked!!! Thanks! Can you please explain the difference to me?

Comment: `$('.toggleAll').on('click', ...` binds a click event to `.toggleAll` elements. `$(document).on('click', '.toggleAll', ...` binds a click event to the document and all its child elements. The reason the first snippet doesn't work is that your `.toggleAll` element doesn't exist on initial runtime (I haven't investigated why; maybe inserted via javascript or ajax?). The  second snippet of code works because it doesn't rely on the `.toggleAll` element existing because it's binding to the `document` itself. This is called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work because the elements are being dynamically generated with jquery. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this code in your website's code:

```
$('.toggleAll').on('click',function(){
    $('.pp, .coat, .heart-wrap, .comment-wrap, .check-wrap, .grip .btn').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

I ran this in the console and the show/hide button started working fine.

Comment: it is on his website. Within the embedded [http://galnova.com/2015/js/g15.js](http://galnova.com/2015/js/g15.js) 
script

Comment: @James Oh yes you're right. But somehow it's not getting its way onto the webpage, perhaps because of accidental comments.

Comment: Or it could be that the button is being loaded after the initial page load i.e. through ajax/javascript and therefore the event handler isn't binding to the button as it doesn't exist *yet*. I haven't investigated it that deeply, though :-)

Comment: @James yeah right, that's the reason in most of such cases. In this case though, even the alert is not firing which means the click handler code is not being executing ever. So there are both possibilities :)

Comment: Thanks all of you guys are amazing!